# How to write a regular expression for persian characters

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

I want to write a regular expression that replace hashtags with somethings in javascript. I use `/#\w+/`, but it is not include persian, arabic and other non-english characters. I want to allow all language characters or at least persian and english characters. How do I do it?